# Will Exact route in parent component block the routes in Children component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I just found that the route in children components won't work if I add "exact" to the routes in parent component. It's difficult for me to explain it without giving my code. Code below will show what I mean.

In App.js

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">

            <Link className='Link' to={"/courses"}>Courses </Link>
            <Link className='Link' to={"/users"}>Users </Link>
            <Switch>
                <Route path={"/users"}  component={Users}/>
                <Route path={"/courses"}  component={Courses}/>
                {/*<Route path={"/courses/course/:id/:courseTitle"} exact component={Course}/>*/}
                {/*<Route path={"/courses/:id/:courseTitle"} exact component={Course}/>*/}



            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
}
}
export default App;
```

If I add exact to the route, then the route in child component won't work.

```
                    <Route path={"/users"} exact component={Users}/>
                <Route path={"/courses"} exact component={Courses}/>
```

Child component:

```
class Courses extends Component {
state = {
    courses: [
        { id: 1, title: 'Angular - The Complete Guide' },
        { id: 2, title: 'Vue - The Complete Guide' },
        { id: 3, title: 'PWA - The Complete Guide' }
    ]
}

render () {
    console.log(this.props.match.url + "/courses/caonima")
    return (

        <div>
            <h1>Amazing Udemy Courses</h1>
            <section className="Courses">
                {
                    this.state.courses.map( course => {
                        console.log(this.props.match.url  + '/' +  course.id + '/' + course.title)
                        return <Link key={course.id} to={{
                            pathname: this.props.match.url + '/' + course.id + '/' + course.title
                        }}>

                        <article className="Course" key={course.id}>{course.title}</article>
                        </Link>
                    } )
                }
            </section>
            <Route path={this.props.match.url +  '/:id/:courseTitle'} exact component={Course}/>
        </div>
    );
}
}
export default Courses;
```

I just don't know why the "exact" would make so.

Comment: yes, it is supposed to be so by design. From the documentation for `exact` - When true, will only match if the path matches the location.pathname exactly.

Comment: Are you sure that when you add `exact` in `<Route>`, then your router of URL is equal your path of `<Route>`?

Comment: I think I know how it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, given `<Route path={"/users"} exact component={Users}/>` then only when a path matches *exactly* "/users" with that route match and render. *Any* subroute can't exactly match that though, because the parent route won't match and render.

In this case it may be easier to think of these "root" routes as sub-domains, you're matching a path prefix, i.e. any path that begins with "/users/..." can match and be rendered. For anything you want to render on *exactly* "/users", then think of that as your fallback route in that domain where nothing else matched so it renders the root sub-route.

[Nesting Routes](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/nesting)

Root Router

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Link className='Link' to={"/courses"}>Courses </Link>
        <Link className='Link' to={"/users"}>Users </Link>
        <Switch>
          <Route path={"/users"}  component={Users}/>
          <Route path={"/courses"}  component={Courses}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Sub-route

```
class Courses extends Component {
  state = {
    courses: [
      { id: 1, title: 'Angular - The Complete Guide' },
      { id: 2, title: 'Vue - The Complete Guide' },
      { id: 3, title: 'PWA - The Complete Guide' }
    ]
  }

  render () {
    console.log(this.props.match.url + "/courses/caonima")
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Amazing Udemy Courses</h1>
        <section className="Courses">
          {
            this.state.courses.map( course => {
              console.log(this.props.match.url  + '/' +  course.id + '/' + course.title)
              return <Link key={course.id} to={{
                pathname: this.props.match.url + '/' + course.id + '/' + course.title
              }}>
                <article className="Course" key={course.id}>{course.title}</article>
              </Link>
            })
          }
        </section>
        <Route path={this.props.match.url +  '/:id/:courseTitle'} exact component={Course}/>
        <Route path={this.props.match.url} component={CoursesHome} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```